# TableView white cell after reloadData

Tags: swift, uitableview

I've a problem after load data from firebase, when i call the reload data, the table view populate with new list data but are all white and if I click I can get the data value correctly.
If I use static data all works fine.
Any suggestion? thanks!

```
private func loadUniversity(url: String) {

        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.ephemeral
        let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration)
        let url = URL(string: url)!

        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) {

            (data, response, error) in

            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200, let data = data else {
                return
            }
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let university = try decoder.decode([UniversityJSON].self, from: data)
                for item in university {
                    self.universityArray.append(University(name: item.university_name.trim()))
                }
                let queue = OperationQueue.main
                queue.addOperation {
                    self.currentUniversityArray = self.universityArray
                    print(self.currentUniversityArray)
                    self.table.reloadData()
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error info: \(error)")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as? UniversityCell else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
        cell.name.text = currentUniversityArray[indexPath.row].name
        return cell
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Show us the cell for row at indexpath please. Also if its made in storyboard send a picture of that too.

Comment: hi @NiallKehoe, this my code

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> 
        UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as? 
       UniversityCell else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
        cell.name.text = currentUniversityArray[indexPath.row].name
        return cell
    }

Comment: try adding cell.name.textColor = UIColor.red , This is just my first guess. It would be good to see the main storyboard

Comment: @StefanoToppi Please do not post code in comments. [Edit] your question to include all relevant details.

Comment: Ok sorry for error

Comment: @StefanoToppi No need to apologize. Simply update you question.

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as? UniversityCell else {
      return UITableViewCell()
   }
   cell.name.text = currentUniversityArray[indexPath.row].name
   // Put this background Color
   cell.backgroundColor = .clear
   return cell
}
```

Comment: Please don't just post code. Include an explanation of what was wrong and how the answer solves the issue.